# Update catalog strategy of large LIVE Magento site

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, full-page-cache

We have an issue in which we have a Magento site of around 150K monthly traffic .

Configuration :

1.dual xeon cpu
2.16gb ram
3.500gb ssd
4.CDN 
5.FPC cache

catalog_flat_tables enabled.

50K skus
100 categories .

Our site works very well.

We have an issue in which , we perform daily catalog updates via the catalog import tool ,and then when we clear the FPC cache , it takes the category page around 1-2 minutes to be rebuilt , during that time the site may seem to be down . 
Not to mention warming up all the category filters cache.

Is there a certain method/strategy we can perform in-order to update the catalog and more importantly clear the FPC cache while the site is live without facing that downtime ?

Is there a better method to update the catalog instead of using the Magento import tool ?

Regards ,

James